# Pandas Remap Values in Column using lists in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping

I have a dataframe with column 'SUBCATEGORY' and I am trying to add a new column 'CATEGORY' using a dictionary to define how each subcategory rolls up.

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'SUBCATEGORY': ['green','blue','yellow','red','12','14','cat','dog','bird']})

test_dict = {'color':['green','blue','yellow','red'],
             'number':['12','14'],
             'animal':['cat','dog','bird']}
```

From here, how do I get something like this:

```
     SUBCATEGORY    CATEGORY
0       green        color
1       blue         color
2       yellow       color
3       red          color
4       12           number
5       14           number
6       cat          animal 
7       dog          animal 
8       bird         animal
```

I tried:

```
test_df['CATEGORY']=test_df['SUBCATEGORY']
test_df=test_df.replace({"CATEGORY": test_dict})
```

and

```
test_df['CATEGORY']=test_df['SUBCATEGORY']
test_df['CATEGORY'].map(mapping_dict)
```

but neither worked, I think because the dictionary values are lists instead of single objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `test_dict` is backwards. Let's take your `map` operation as an example.

The input is the subcategory, so `green`, `blue`, etc.

Calling `map` is, under the hood, calling something like `test_dict['green']`.

Instead, reverse your map, so that entries in the dictionary map to the subcategory it should map to. You can use that instead.

```py
mapping_dict = {subcat: cat for cat, subcat_list in test_dict.items() for subcat in subcat_list}

"""
{'green': 'color',
 'blue': 'color',
 'yellow': 'color',
 'red': 'color',
 '12': 'number',
 '14': 'number',
 'cat': 'animal',
 'dog': 'animal',
 'bird': 'animal'}
"""

test_df['CATEGORY'] = test_df['SUBCATEGORY'].map(mapping_dict)

# OR

test_df['CATEGORY']=test_df['SUBCATEGORY']
test_df=test_df.replace({"CATEGORY": mapping_dict})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can invert `test_dict` first.

```
inverted_dict = {v: k for k, values in test_dict.items() for v in values}
test_df['CATEGORY'] = test_df['SUBCATEGORY'].map(inverted_dict)
print(test_df)
```

```
  SUBCATEGORY CATEGORY
0       green    color
1        blue    color
2      yellow    color
3         red    color
4          12   number
5          14   number
6         cat   animal
7         dog   animal
8        bird   animal
```